# Optimal control for pairs trading?

Tags: market-making

My trading scenario is essentially pairs trading 'identical' futures pairs from different exchanges, similar to arbitrage but for futures.

One side is entered with limit orders and the opposite side is entered with market orders so that overall I am price neutral.

I make money from the ratio between the prices of the two products, which is very close to 1.0 but deviates over time.

What I am trading is a synthetic market composed of these ratios which is highly mean reverting.

My question is, can I still use the optimal stochastic control work of [Avellaneda-Stoikov](https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/avellane/HighFrequencyTrading.pdf) or is there more work I should be looking at here to make sure the prices I'm posting are optimal for the market?